# Different screen orientation on different devices when landscape mode

Tags: android, android-orientation

I am using

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

for my Activity and I am trying to use `OrientationEventListener` to find the orientation of the device. On some devices my landscape orientation is showing values around **270** and other devices shows values around **0**. On every device where the Home button is placed the orientation value shows **0**. I want to have same values when holding the all devices in landscape mode. Is there a flag that can show me which device is showing 270 or 0 for landscape mode as default orientation.

This is my `OrientationEventListener`

```
    mOrientationListener = new OrientationEventListener(this,
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL) {

        @Override
        public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {

            Log.v("Orientation changed to ", String.valueOf(orientation));

        }
    };
```

Is there a trick that can help to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I have found the solution.**

With this code I am getting the default display rotation:

```
int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
```

in the body of my `onOrientationChanged` method I can make this:

```
            if (rotation == 0) {
                if (orientation  >= 90 && orientation <= 270) {

                } 
            } else if (rotation == 1) {
                if (orientation < 180 && orientation > 0 ) {

                }
            }
```

This will enter the if only if my device is not in the correct landscape position. If my device is on 90+ angle I can give the user a message.